# EF Core Scaffolding an Oracle Database - Pass OracleConfiguration into the connection string

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-scaffolding

Here's the situation. I have a .Net Core 6 Console app that reads data from an Oracle database using the following configuration:

```
var connectionString = "User Id=MY_USER;Password=MY_PASSWORD;Data Source=MY_DATASOURCE;"    

OracleConfiguration.DirectoryServers = "(my.directory.server:123:456)";
OracleConfiguration.DirectoryServerType = "AD"
OracleConfiguration.DefaultAdminContext = "cn=my_cn,dc=my_dc_1,dc=my_dc_2"
OracleConfiguration.NamesDirectoryPath = "(LDAP)"
OracleConfiguration.SqlNetAuthenticationServices = "(NONE,NTS)"

_ = services.AddDbContext<DbContext, MyDbContext>(options =>
{
   _ = options.UseOracle(connectionString);
});
```

This works prefectly fine.

Now I need to scaffold the said Oracle database using

```
dotnet-ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id=MY_USER;Password=MY_PASSWORD;Data Source=MY_DATASOURCE;" "Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore"
```

This returns the following error *ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified*

This was expected since I did not include all the custom *OracleConfiguration* into the connection string passed to *dotnet-ef*

How can I include those custom *OracleConfiguration* into the connection string ?

Comment: After doing some research, I don't think it's possible to include such configurations into the connection string itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have made a more torough search before asking this question but I will share my findings anyhow.

As it turns out, the server name (or server's ip) should be used, to avoid relying on a TNS resolution that was causing the exception in the first place (*ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified*).

```
dotnet-ef dbcontext scaffold "User Id=MY_USER;Password=MY_PASSWORD;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MY_DB_SERVER_NAME)(PORT=MY_PORT)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MY_DB_NAME)));" "Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore"
```